# Python Function to add column items to list based around criteria from a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

[Code Sample] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx1UH.png)

I have created this code to show the percentage of missing values for each of these columns, how can I now create a new variable that contains only the column names for the columns with over X% missing values?

Assumed it would be an if statement but not too sure what it should do.

[List based on DF.loc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvUSr.png)

Progress based on below comment

Edit 2:

```
# make a list of the categorical variables that contain missing values
cat_vars2 = X_train.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
len(cat_vars2)

print(cat_vars2.isnull().sum())

# print percentage of missing values per variable
percent_missing = cat_vars2.isnull().sum() * 100 / len(cat_vars2)
missing_value_cat_vars = pd.DataFrame({'column_name': cat_vars2.columns,
                                 'percent_missing': percent_missing})

missing_value_cat_vars.sort_values('percent_missing', inplace=True)
print(missing_value_cat_vars)
```

[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q5Dj.png)

```
variables to impute with the string missing

with_string_missing=list(missing_value_cat_vars.loc[missing_value_cat_vars['percent_missing']>=10,'column_name'])
                        
print(with_string_missing)

# variables to impute with the most frequent category

with_frequent_category=list(missing_value_cat_vars.loc[missing_value_cat_vars['percent_missing']<90,'column_name'])

print(with_frequent_category)
```

[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwiuQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
threshold = 1 #can be whatever you want
df.loc[df['percent_missing'] >= threshold, column_name]
```

If you want it as a list just do:

```
list(df.loc[df['percent_missing'] >= threshold, column_name])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I have tried using what you suggested, however, it is now bringing up the column names twice and also showing the column name and its D:type at the end of each list, is there any way to prevent this happening?

Comment: I think by wrapping it in [] you are actually converting it into a 2D array, which is why you are having the problem. Try list()

Comment: Hi, thanks for the list suggestion, that is working perfected. i have realised, however, that the list is meant to show the data with less than 10% of all the data missing is also including all the variables with no data missing, can you please advise if there is a way, I can ensure these are not being picked up by mistake? I have included the code in Edit 2 along with the outputs. Sorry I really am trying to understand this, it's just taking me a while.

Comment: Just chain the .loc statements:

`list(df.loc[((df['percent_missing'] >= threshold) & (df['percent_missing'] != 0)), column_name])`